# Preg_replace, замена всего, что не совпадает с шаблоном

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток.

Сейчас делаю графическую оболочку для движка, и возникла проблема с подстановкой и разборкой времени. На входе строка вида "04.01.2015 в 08.34", плюс пользователь может ввести еще лишнее символы, нужно оставить только "04.01.2015 08.34".

Вот регулярка, которую я начал делать:

```
'/(3[0-1]|[0-2]{0,1}[0-9])\.(1[0-2]|0{0,1}[0-9])\.(([0-9]{2}){0,1}[0-9]{2})/'
```

Comment: ставлю традиционные пять баксов на то, что подход изначально неправильный, и парсить эту строку вообще не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new DateTime(preg_replace('/[^\d\s.]/','','11.11 dfb 04.01.2015 v asd'));
```

Подчищаем мусор, передаем в любом формате умному datetime и получаем еще и удобный-стандартный объект даты.

Comment: спасибо, я уже давненько написал свой велосипед) тоже работает на отлично

Answer (score 0):

Ваша регулярка зачем-то отдельно выделяет 20 в 2014. Уберите вложенные круглые скобки.

После даты идут любые символы (не менее одного), значит пишем .+

Затем, идут часы и минуты аналогично дате.

Затем, идут возможные дополнительные символы .*

Answer (score 0):

Можно делать это как-то так:

```
$re = <<<HEREDOC
    ^ # начало строки
    (?:
        (?P<date> # первая сохраненная группа
            (?:3[0-1]|[0-2]{0,1}[0-9])\\.(?:1[0-2]|0{0,1}[0-9])\\.(?:(?:[0-9]{2}){0,1}[0-9]{2})
        ) # конец первой группы
        (?P<time> # вторая группа. Должна искать время
            (?:0?+[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])[.:][0-5][0-9](?!\\.)
        )
    ){0}
    (?:
        .*?((?P>date)).*?((?P>time)) |
        .*?((?P>time)).*?((?P>date))
    )
    .*$ # ну и захватываем весь пришедший текст
HEREDOC;
$arr = Array(
    "04.01.2015 v 18.34",
    "sd 04.01.2015 v 18.34 asd",
    "11.11 dfb 04.01.2015 v asd"
);
foreach ( $arr as $k=>$v ) {
    echo preg_replace( "/$re/xu", "$3$6 $4$5", $v)."\n";
};
```

Результат:

```
04.01.2015 18.34
04.01.2015 18.34
04.01.2015 11.11
```

Если что-то непонятно, я не виноват :)
http://ideone.com/g5RzuZ

Comment: спасибо) я разберусь)